# mvc ajax doesnt work when I try to call an action in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to send quantity info and product id to a controller using ajax. after I clicked addtocart button and nothing happened,page didnt refreshed. I refreshed the page manually and saw that requested quantity added to cart successfully. Why the page does not refresh automatically?
Can you please help me what wrong is here?

```
<script>  
    $("#addtocart").click(function () {

        alert("tıklandı");
        var val1;
        var val2;
        val1 = $(".cart_quantity_input").val();
        val2 = $(".product-name-text").attr("id");
        alert("değerler alındı");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Home/AddToCart/",
            data: { id: val2, quantity: val1 },
            success: function (Data) {
                alert("ajak içindeyiz");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
        alert("ajak bitti");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: is request being made? Note your code is not wrapped in `$(document).ready`. Event may not even be attached

Comment: I check where I stuck using alerts. I get all alerts except the one inside ajax success.

Comment: in that case need to inspect actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. See what status is and what is returned (if any)

Comment: Do you have any script errors in the page ? Open your browser console/network tab and see what happens when you click on the add to cart

Comment: Is your action method name **AddToCartAddToCart** ?

Comment: I have changed the method name AddToCart but still doesnt work. I have checked in network tab and get "xhr" type something file in every 6 seconds. what is this?

Comment: That might be the calls for browserlink. But when you click on add to cart, what you see in your console/network tab ?

Comment: In console it says just "Uncaught TypeError: $.scrollUp is not a function." but after I clicked addtocart button and nothing happened, I refreshed the page I saw that requested quantity added to cart successfully. then I wanted to add another two quantities, clicked addtocart button then refreshed the page again but saw just one item added.

Comment: You should first fix your script error ("$.scrollUp is not a function"). You probably forgot to include a plugin in your page. Also, do not hardcode the path to your action method. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683420/ajax-call-to-mvc5-actionresult/34683471#34683471

Comment: I have fixed scrollUp script error. but I think it is about something else. page doesnt refresh automatically.

Comment: Use that error function and find out the error...

Answer (score 0):

You're using an Ajax function to send your data. I would normally use Ajax specifically to avoid the page being refreshed. If you want to refresh the page then you should be using a form with a submit button to your controller instead.

However, I expect the issue with your success function not being hit is because you are specifying the data type as json. This is telling the Ajax function that json data is expected both ways so your controller action should return json. As a guess, it looks more like:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id, int quantity)
{
    // blah blah blah
    return View();
}
```

If this is the case then remove the datatype parameter from your ajax call and it should then hit the success function.

But you should either be returning json or a ContentResult from the action and then add logic to update the cart display based on the results. Or use a form and submit the data if you want to refresh the whole page.

Comment: I wanted to add product to the cart with AddToCard button with the quantity coming from input value. But I couldn't pass this quantity data with html.actionlink thats why I had to use ajax. I solved the refresh problem calling html.actionlink to the same Product Detail page. thanks for you helps.